# Pressing alt-gr locks on compose mode, how do I disable this? so its just for one character

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, compose-key

When I am typing I want to be able to use the compose key to get at "dead" characters, if I press the compose key simultaneously with the key I want I can toggle dead mode, for the next key I press.

however, if I press the compose key alone, all subsequent keypresses give me their level 2 symbols. I don't know how to go back to normal key symbols... this compose mode seems to be locked on forever.

As an example in below, the first line is typed "123..." then I press <kbd>alt-gr</kbd> by itself...  then I type "123..." again but now I get all the compose versions and not the normal numbers. (this is a French keyboard in this example)

example...

normal typing <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>  gives me 1234567890

I press <kbd>alt-gr</kbd> once then <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>... gives me &é"'(-è_çà

now the only way to go back to 1,2,3,4,5 etc is to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> etc

The keyboard is locked into the compose mode and I need to restart to get it out of this mode, (or change it to a different language).

to be clear, it seems that on my keyboard entering this "compose mode" is a permanent effect, and lasts for longer than just the subsequent keypresses, I want it to turn off after the next keypress.

Comment: if your familiar with the concept of compose keys, imagine a mode where all key presses register as there compose variations, with no access to the non-compose versions

Comment: Your question and comments confuse me. Can you please edit your question and let us know exactly which keyboard layout you are using and provide a few specific characters which you can't type successfully as expected. I think it would be easier to guide you with that information.

Comment: I appreciate your help, i tried to rewrite the question to better explain

Comment: From your latest description, it appears to me as if it switches to some other keyboard layout. Have you possibly defined <AltGr> as a shortcut for switching layouts?

Comment: not knowingly, how would i establish this?

Comment: Please run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` and let us know what it outputs.

Comment: >gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['lv3:caps_switch']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74765/discussion-between-joe-lovick-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a custom keyboard layout that had an issue, disabling this keyboard layout and restarting my machine, stopped the problem on other keyboard layouts.

I now need to find the problem with this keyboard layout, but that as they say is a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you have defined <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose), its original behavior is overridden.

To disable the compose key, and with that retain the original behavior of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, you can use *Tweaks* (`gnome-tweak-tool`) or run this terminal command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Comment: so I have reset all bindings, and it doesn't help, it appears this is a feature by design, see pomsky's answer, I just need the Alt-GR to only impact the next character, not all subsequent characters.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the default behaviour of the French keyboard.

[image]

As per the keyboard layout above, if you press <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, you're supposed to get

```
&é"'(-è_çà
```

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> instead, you should get

```
1234567890
```

So "pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>" part seems to be a red herring.

Comment: OK, i can buy that... it behaves as you describe.. how do i turn it off when it is on so that i can go back to getting 1 to be 1... ideally pressing the Alt-Gr would only work on the next keypress, like it does on the mac

Comment: See Gunnar's answer.

Comment: unfortunatly that doesnt solve the problem. i do need to get at compose characters, i just need to be switch back to normal characters after i have typed one.